# Get unique strings based on a substring in C#

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, data-structures, unique

I have a text file which contains almost 100000 entries. All of them are in certain pattern, like
`word1 word2 word3 word4`

However a number of these entries are duplicate where all the words are same. When I am trying to read and form an array or list of the unique ones, I am using an intermediate hash set to do so. And it works pretty fine.
But what essentially I would like to achieve is only unique entries for word2. As in if word2 is common and all other are different, I would like to keep any one of the entries.
e.g
`cat dog lion tiger`
`cat dog deer bear`
`mouse rat bear deer`
`lion tiger cat dog`
`cat dog deer bear`

The desired output in this case would be:
`cat dog lion tiger`
`mouse rat bear deer`
`lion tiger cat dog`

or
`cat dog deer bear`
`mouse rat bear deer`
`lion tiger cat dog`

Currently what the hash set is giving is:

`cat dog lion tiger`
`cat dog deer bear`
`mouse rat bear deer`
`lion tiger cat dog`

Any suggestions as to how can this be achieved efficiently given the data set is large. Is using regex the only option here? I am using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go over the data and put the second word in a dictionary to know if it appeared before.
Code example:

```
    string[] file = {   "cat dog lion tiger",
                    "cat dog deer bear",
                    "mouse rat bear deer",
                    "lion tiger cat dog",
                    "cat dog deer bear"};

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    foreach (string s in file)
    {
        string[] words = s.Split(' ');
        // assumption - thare are at least 2 words in a line - validate it
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(words[1]))
        {
            lst.Add(s);
            dict.Add(words[1], words[1]);
        }
    }

    foreach (string s1 in lst)
        Console.WriteLine(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an auxiliar class to store the string and implements the interface IEqualityComparer to HashSet,

Example:

```
        HashSet<WordsRow> list = new HashSet<WordsRow>(new WordsRow());

        list.Add(new WordsRow("cat dog lion tiger"));
        list.Add(new WordsRow("cat dog deer bear"));
        list.Add(new WordsRow("mouse rat bear deer"));
        list.Add(new WordsRow("lion tiger cat dog"));
        list.Add(new WordsRow("cat dog deer bear"));


        foreach (WordsRow row in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row.Row);
        }
```

"WordRow class" must contain the following::

```
public class WordsRow : IEqualityComparer<WordsRow>
{
    public string Row {get; set;}

    public WordsRow() { }

    public WordsRow(string row)
    {
        this.Row = row;                        
    }

    public bool Equals(WordsRow x, WordsRow y)
    {
        return x.Row.Split(' ')[1] == y.Row.Split(' ')[1];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(WordsRow obj)
    {
        return obj.Row.Split(' ')[1].GetHashCode();
    }
}
```